# How to make an element go below a different floated element

Tags: html, css

Im sure it is a very simple fix that i just can't see. I want the second button on the left hand side to be below the one on the right hand side in terms of height on the page but still on the left hand side. I have included a JS fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/fraserdale/knpvwhad/ 
Thanks for your help in advanced

```
<div >
    <p>
        <select id="shipping" style="float: right;">
            <option value="-40">UK / AUS $40 </option>
            <option value="-13.95">US $13.95</option>
            <option value="-30">CAN $30</option>
            <option value="0">Free</option>
        </select>


        Shipping:
    </p>
</div>

    <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

and the CSS

```
.button {
        background-color: #41ad33;
        border: none;
        color: white;
        padding: 15px 32px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    select{
        padding: 15px 9.25px ;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 16px;
        margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
        cursor: pointer;
```

Comment: Why not just float the button to the right as well? https://jsfiddle.net/knpvwhad/1/

Comment: That doesn't work it messes it up and puts it in the middle

Comment: I do not see the second button, I just can see one button on the right hand side. Maybe you forgot a piece of code bro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the button to be a block level element and then use [clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clear) property:

```css
.button {
  background-color: #41ad33;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  clear: right;
}

select {
  padding: 15px 9.25px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <select id="shipping" style="float: right;">
      <option value="-40">UK / AUS $40 </option>
      <option value="-13.95">US $13.95</option>
      <option value="-30">CAN $30</option>
      <option value="0">Free</option>
    </select> Shipping:
  </p>
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: @jordanS this is what i was looking for. Thanks for trying to help

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a float, I would suggest using a flexbox container. Using the property `justify-content: space-between;` you can make sure that your select is aligned all the way to the right. Another benefit is that you can vertically align items in a flexbox with `align-items: center;`, which will remove the need to further position the label aswel.

For more info on flexbox, see: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```
.button {
  background-color: #41ad33;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  clear:both;
}
select{
  padding: 15px 9.25px ;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 4px 2px 4px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
label {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.input-container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

<div class="input-container">
  <label for="shipping">
    Shipping:
  </label> 
  <select id="shipping">
    <option value="-40">UK / AUS $40 </option>
    <option value="-13.95">US $13.95</option>
    <option value="-30">CAN $30</option>
    <option value="0">Free</option>
  </select>
</div>

<button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a new element with the  clear:both property to put the floating element below your right button like this
https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/13rt8eom/

```
<div >
        <p>
            <select id="shipping" style="float: right;">
                <option value="-40">UK / AUS $40 </option>
                <option value="-13.95">US $13.95</option>
                <option value="-30">CAN $30</option>
                <option value="0">Free</option>
            </select>


            Shipping:
        </p>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <button class="button" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
    </div>
```